# How to change (return) a pointer in a recursive function which is a function parameter in the function

Tags: c, recursion, graph, linked-list, depth-first-search

I am currently studying graphs. I have a recursive program which finds all possible paths between two nodes.
My function for finding paths works fine. However, I want to save these paths and sort them based on how many nodes do they have. And I thought, I can use a linked list.

Here is my struct:

```
typedef struct path{
    int *cities;
    int num_of_cities;
    struct path* next;
}PATH;
```

Function for finding paths:

```
void find_path(GRAPH* graph, PATH* all_paths, int* path, int path_index, int from, int to){

    if(from == to){
        //A path has been found. 
        int i;
        PATH *newPath = create_path(path_index);
        newPath->next = all_paths;
        all_paths = newPath;
        
        for(i=0;i<path_index;i++){
            newPath->cities[i] = path[i];
        }
        newPath->cities[i] = to; //last node is not in the path array, so save it like this
    
    }   
    else{
        graph->visited[from] = 1;
        path[path_index] = from;
        path_index++;
        
        NODE* tmp = graph->AdjList[from];
        
        while(tmp){
            if(!graph->visited[tmp->vertex])
                find_path(graph, all_paths, path, path_index, tmp->vertex, to);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        
        graph->visited[from] = 0;
        path_index--;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

And here is my main:

```
int main(){
    /*
    .
    some code...
    */
    PATH *p1 = NULL; //head(pointer) of the linked list that stores all possible paths
    /*
    .
    .
    some code...
    .
    .
    */
    find_path(g1, p1, path, path_index, 0, 5);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is, since the function is recursive I can't save the pointer of "all_paths", after changing it. After each iteration the pointer sets to NULL which is the initial value. Is there any way that I can save the pointer after making changes and pass is to other iterations or is it impossible. I am open for all suggestions.

Comment: Pass it back as the function's `return` value. You are wasting an opportunity by having a `void` function.

Comment: I tried that, but after the function returns in the "while" the "all_paths" sets to NULL. But i will try again.

Comment: If you tried that, extract a [mcve] from that attempt and include that in your question here. Also, what is the precise behaviour you expect? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: If a route is found from a node, return a pointer to its route's linked list, which the calling instance can deal with. Otherwise return `NULL`

Comment: Guys, thanks for the  help. I figured out after trying again with changing the return type, I believe. But I need to make sure it saves all paths. but it is definitely returning the linked list head.